# What is the best way to abandon sessions and clear cache on logout

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am new to C# and .NET Core. I am preparing a logout functionality in which I need to add code to the kill/abandon sessions and clear the cache similar to the following code written in C#:

```
Session.Abandon();
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

I am using the following code to kill/abandon the sessions and clear the cache in my C# application running on .NET Core:

```
HttpContext.Session.Clear();
 
foreach (var cookie in Request.Cookies.Keys)
{
    if (cookie == ".AspNetCore.Session")
    {
        HttpContext.Session.Remove(cookie);
        HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie);
    }
}
```

What would be the best way to kill/abandon sessions and clear the cache similar in C# running on .NET Core?

Comment: Please follow the site's tagging guidelines by not putting tags in your question titles.

Comment: What is it you think that "clearing the cache" does, exactly? In the example you provided above, it's simply telling the browser not to cache that specific response. I'm not sure how this benefits you.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will remove all cookies.

Call `ExpireAllCookies()` function where you want to clear all cookies

```
private void ExpireAllCookies()
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            {
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                int cookieCount = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Count;
                for (var i = 0; i < cookieCount; i++)
                {
                    var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[i];
                    if (cookie != null)
                    {
                        var expiredCookie = new HttpCookie(cookie.Name)
                        {
                            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
                            Domain = cookie.Domain
                        };
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(expiredCookie); // overwrite it
                    }
                }

                // clear cookies server side
                HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Clear();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Server side..

Session.Clear stays in the same session.
Session.Clear will just clear the session data , the session is still alive

Session.Abandon dumps the current session and starts a new session.
Session_End will be fired and next request will fire Session_Start

Session ID will remain same in both cases, as long as the browser is not
closed

Client side..

add this script your header

Response.AddHeader("Cache-control", "no-store, must-revalidate, private,no-cache");
Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
Response.AddHeader("Expires", "0");